# get lines in file via index from another file

Tags: python, python-2.7

i have two files, first my big list:

```
123 321 231 412
424 244 bear wolf
512 dinosaur 525
```

second one with the index i want from the first one, so

```
1   
-1
3
```

Now i want as an output the exact lines from the first file via the specific index of the second one, note: if i have a '-1' i want to just skip it.

So in the example:

```
123 321 231 412
512 dinosaur 525
```

i tried this:

```
import linecache

i = open('list_wanted', 'w')

with open ('index_list', 'r') as index:
     for line in index:
          int_index = [int(i) for i in line.split()] # this seems necessary since my index list seems to be in strings, not integers

     for line in int_index:
          if line != ('-1'):
               i.write(linecache.getline('big_list' , line))
```

I really dont want the whole big_list in my memory, so the linecache seems fine, but i can't get it to work properly. What am i doing wrong?

---

:edit:
The first answer was correct, but i have a very weird result now:
the length does not match from what i was expecting, i added a small counter w:

```
import linecache

w = 0

a = open('lines_wanted', 'w')

with open ('index_list', 'r') as index:
     int_index = [int(i), for i in index.readlines()]

     for line in int_index:
          a.write(linecache.getline('big_list', line))
          w = w + 1

print(w)
```

the number of times i write (w) is the expected number of lines, but if i check my file i have some lines less (expected 34752 (thats the same as my w) and got in fact only 34308).
i think this might be a problem with duplicates, how can i avoid it and get my expected w lines in my file.
Does someone has an idea?
I NEED exactly as many lines as in my index_list file.

P.s.: the case of -1 is not an issue anymore, i got rid of it, so i have really only the "good" lines that i want in my index_list file.

:edit2:
found it, i had to write line+1 in my write command

Comment: does the order of indices matter? if the second file would contain: `5 3 -1 1 -1 2 7 ...`

Comment: hmm, well i have it already in this order, and it is there for a specific reason i worked previously

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import linecache

i = open('lines_wanted', 'w')

with open('index_list', 'r') as index:
    # this seems necessary since my index list seems to be in strings, not integers
    int_index = [int(i) for i in index.readlines()]  

    for line in int_index:
        if line != ('-1'):
            i.write(linecache.getline('big_list', line))
```

The problem was with the `int_index` list. It was not being formed as expected.

Comment: Seems better, but now i cannot write (error 'str object has no attribute write') but i have my file "i" open and i said i.write :edit: whatever, i use i twice, i am dumb, Thanks, its still running, i will see if it will be right!

Comment: It works, but i get the wrong number of lines (less then i want, see my edit)